# added Office 365 licenses, broke launching

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, license

Using our cloud session through VMWare, we had it all set up so that anyone on a certain "tier" would have access to Word, Excel, Power Point, Access, basically everything but Outlook which was through office.com. Worked great, everyone could launch it, would not prompt for user credentials. Had to get into office.com for email. No problems. We were running out of licenses, so more were purchased and the licensing was updated. This no longer works as it once did. Everyone was getting prompted to log in. Everyone had access to it, but had to keep logging in with every new cloud session. Our call volume was crazy. With a very small IT department, we made the decision to change the access from everyone uses it through office.com to full office licenses. For an additional cost (well over $4k a month), everyone once again works. Not everyone *needs* full office, just mostly access to Outlook. Looking for a way to set this back the way it was. We contacted our cloud hosting company, and they...didn't help much other than saying they didn't know how they original set it up, or that it shouldn't have been set up that way to being with.

I did see this similar question ([Office 2016: Disallow sign-in to Office, but continue using Office 365 email in Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/1272590/office-2016-disallow-sign-in-to-office-but-continue-using-office-365-email-in)) but am not convinced that these are the same issue. Looking for clarification if it is, and if so, will try it out.

Comment: Do you mean the client users are prompted for credentials when using Outlook for Exchange Online mailbox after update the Office licenses? How did you update the licenses? What's the detailed license changes? In Outlook client, click File > Office Account, check the account under User Information and Product Information.

Comment: This is all for MS Office, installed on a virtual windows 7 PC. The end users were getting prompted to log into office when launching any office application (Word, Excel, PPT) and they were going to office.com to check their email. It started prompting after adding more licenses were added to our pool of licenses. (I guess) The change was made by our provider.