# Can't login to Office 365 Account on Outlook 2019 using EnableADAL 0

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, exchange

Recently reinstalled Windows 10 and have been setting up my email accounts on Outlook 2019.

Managed to login fine with both of my Outlook accounts (@hotmail, @live) as well as my university's o365 account, however when I opened any other Office 2019 application (Word, Powerpoint etc.) I was logged in to all 3 accounts. I would prefer to not be logged into any account on Office applications unless I specifically choose to.

I did some researching and came across a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1288410/1757518) thread where someone had the similar issue and added the following registry key:

HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\EnableADAL=0

This works for both of my Outlook accounts. I can login normally on Outlook, open Word and won't be logged in. However, I can no longer login to my o365 account on Outlook. Enabling ADAL allows o365 to authenticate and connect to Outlook, but then it goes back to the original issue of logging in to all microsoft apps on all accounts.

I don't want o365 and want to keep all Office products not signed in to any account.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you add the O365account into Access work or school.

Comment: Even if I add the o365 account to Access work or school I still can't access emails on Outlook. When I attempt to add the account on Outlook it brings up the legacy login window, pressing Ok closes the window then just reopens it again.

Comment: Can you provide a pop-up dialog?